# How to force Meteor to rerender immediately, or prioritize reactive update?

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-blaze

I'm experimenting with building my own loading spinner and the way I have it set up is with a helper that check if entry arrays are empty.

```
{{#if viewThisPage}}
  {{#if noEntriesLoaded}}
    <div class="loadingSpinner">...</div>
  {{/if}}
  {{#each entry}}
    {{ > myTemplate}}
  {{/each}}
{{/if}}
```

Initially viewThisPage is false. When viewThisPage is set to true I query mongoDB for entries. The issue that I'm seeing from benchmarking is that the query goes so fast that all the DOM update events are squished together so that the spinner never gets rendered, in other words, noEntriesLoaded is true for too short a time.

There is, however, around a 1200ms lag between triggering viewThisPage and the page actually rendering. I want the spinner to display during this period of lag.

Three ways I've thought of to fix this

1. Somehow force meteor to rerender the section immediately after setting viewThisPage while entries haven't loaded yet.
2. Somehow prioritize the reactive response to viewThisPage so that it updates before the entires are loaded.
3. Add fake lag using setTimeout() on the block that adds entries. This works and I get to see my pretty loading spinner but is the dumbest idea ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show spinner while your entries are being rendering.

This code will hide loadingSpinner only when all entries are rendered:

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

```
<template name="Main">
  {{#if viewThisPage}}
    {{#if entriesAreNotReady}}
      <div class="loadingSpinner">...</div>
    {{/if}}
    {{> Entries entry=entry onRendered=onEntriesRendered}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="Entries">
  {{#each entry}}
    {{> myTemplate}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

```
Template.Main.onCreated(function() {
  this.areEntriesRendered = new ReactiveVar(false);
});

Template.Main.helpers({
  onEntriesRendered: function() {
    var areEntriesRendered = Template.instance().areEntriesRendered;

    return function() {
      areEntriesRendered.set(true);
    };
  },

  entriesAreNotReady: function() {
    return ! Template.instance().areEntriesRendered.get();
  }
});

Template.Entries.onRendered(function() {
  this.data.onRendered();
});
```

P.S. Possibly you will need to check that entries are loaded before you render `Entries` template